# How can I craft a sword in Mine Blocks game?

Tags: mine-blocks

I am playing Mine Blocks - which is a free **[2d Minecraft Game](http://2dminecraft.com/view/132/mine-blocks/)** and starting to mine blocks. However, after mining many blocks, I do not know the formula to craft the sword.

I have read the rules of the game but they didn't help. How can I craft a sword?

Answer (score 5):

I played the game in the link you provided, and figured out making a sword is just easy.

You first get wood and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to enter your inventory. **Use the wood to make planks.** 
[image: Crafting Table!]
**After that, make a crafting table using your wood.**

Use your crafting table by <kbd>RClick</kbd> and then craft **Sticks**.

**Finally, use the following recipe to make your Wooden Sword!**
[image: Wooden Sword!]

Answer (score -5):

As MushroomCloudsPlus said, you have to craft a sword by putting 2 wood, cobblestone, gold ingots, iron ingots, or diamonds at the top vertically and a stick at the bottom. You need to do this in the crafting table. You can of course make other tools and the other stuff too, which the recipes are the same as in normal Minecraft:

[image: CRAFTINGTIME!]

Have fun playing 2D Minecraft.

Comment: That's literally stealing the exact same picture as the previous answer.